# Assumptions on a multiple linear regression model and elastic net

Tags: multiple-regression, model, elastic-net

I am interested in using elastic net regression in place of an multiple linear regression. I know when you perform a multiple linear regression you should check the assumptions such making sure the model has constant variance, normality of residuals, etc.

My question is - if I am to use elastic net - do I have to check these assumptions for this as well?

Any comments and help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What are you fitting the model for? If for prediction, you may not need to if the predicted values are OK.

Comment: I am fitting for prediction

Comment: Well, you only need to check for constant variance, normality of residuals, etc if you want to do inference on the model, such as assess statistical significance of estimated coefficients. So you don't need to do this at all if you are only interested in quality of fitted values. I'd be more concerned with the linearity assumption inherit in the model, i.e. effects are linear. What about interactions (these get tricky in standard lasso/elastic net models)?

Comment: Normality of errors is NOT an assumption of a multiple linear regression model (quite a common mistake, I have noticed). Due to the central limit theorem, you parameter estimates will be asymptotically normally distributed even when the errors follow some other distribution. You would typically wish for normal errors only if you wanted exact small sample results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, normality of residuals (Ei ~ N(0, sigma^2) is a formal assumption of the (classical, unregularized) multivariate linear regression model.  See e.g. equation 7.7 (p. 229) of Neter, Wasserman, and Kutner, Applied Linear Statistical Models, 3rd Ed.  The same text says (p. 247), "Box plots and normal probability plots of the residuals are useful for examining whether the error terms are reasonably normally distributed" for the same multivariate linear model.  One can still use a model for prediction if a sample dataset violates some of the model's assumptions.  Presumably in such cases the modeling process has yielded at least a satisfactory out-of-sample error rate.  In the case of a regression model, I'd want to see the shape of the projections of the model's response surface into one or two independent variables closely matching the shape of the same projections for the generating process, across all individual and paired independent variables.  Substantial departures from linearity would give me pause.